# What URL do I use to open a String object in a web browser

Tags: java, testing, selenium, selenium-webdriver, browser

If I have a HTML String object, using Selenium in Java, how can I get the browser to open that String as a HTML page?   I have seen this done before but **I don't remember the format that the URL needs to be**.

For this example, let's say the string is :

```
<h2>This is a <i>test</i></h2>
```

I [looked through this page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI_scheme#Official_IANA-registered_schemes) and couldn't find the answer but I might be overlooking it.  For example I tried this URL and it didn't work for me:

```
data:<h2>This is a <i>test</i></h2>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a link for documentation http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme. You need to specify MIME-type of data. Try `data:text/html,<h2>This is a <i>test</i></h2>`